# how to show default date as string in IQDropdownTextfield?

Tags: ios, swift, date, uitextfield

I have one textfield with class of **IQDropDownTextfield**. I want to use it as date picker.

But my issue is when I want to set date(in string format) before open Pickerview then it is not working.

I add my code below:

```
import IQDropDownTextField
```

Also add `IQDropDownTextFieldDelegate` to controller.

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtDOB: IQDropDownTextField!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    txtDOB.dropDownMode = .datePicker
    txtDOB.isOptionalDropDown = true
    txtDOB.datePicker.maximumDate = Date()
    txtDOB.delegate = self
    txtDOB.selectedItem = "2020-03-18"
}
```

now I have date for display at initial stage as **2020-03-18** and I want to show it as default text in textfield. txtDOB.text is not working because it is deprecated in that library.

still textfield is blank.

Comment: why to choose IQDropDownTextfield instead a uiDatePicker to pick date in iOS.

Comment: You are right @kjoe, But according my project requirement I need to use it. I have only this issue only for one textfield.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting dropdown mode to .datePicker or .dateTimePicker in **IQDropDownTextfield**, `txtDOB.selectedItem` property will not work for you.

you can set text like this
`txtDOB.setDate("2020-03-18".toDate(currentFormate: "yyyy-MM-dd"), animated: true)`.

**.toDate** method should return Date.

I know it's late but it will help others like me. I was facing same issue and I was looking for help.